# Cannot resolve Method getSupportFragmentManager() or ((FragmentActivity)activity)getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, fragment

I want to launch a fragment from my BroadcastReciver class because I want to launch a fragment on a mobile home screen just like a dialog. using that user will stop or snooze the alarm. how to achieve that?

I tried all solutions available at StackOverflow but I can't get an answer. every time I am getting an error.

> Cannot resolve Method getSupportFragmentManager()

or

> Cannot resolve FragmentActivity in
> ((FragmentActivity)activity)getSupportFragmentManager()

any suggestion or question? comment below

Comment: You need to launch the intent first, move to the activity then you can launch the fragment.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer But how can I launch a fragment from activity at the time of alarm? This can only be done in the 'BroadcastReceiver' class. If you know how? answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Activity to host that Fragment. A Fragment cannot be possible without a hosting Activity. At first, create an Activity (eg. `AlarmActivity`) with transparent background (You can achieve with themes) which has a `FragmentContainerView` to host your fragment. When you receive broadcast in your `BroadcastReceiver`, start this activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // This is required
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Is it possible to launch any dialog or DilogFragement instead of an activity?

Comment: How to finish that activity when the user snoozes or finish that alarm.

Comment: First: No, not possible to launch dialog with intent. Second: When user snoozing, perform your required task and call finish() in that Activity, it will exit. If you want to call from within fragment, then requireActivity().finish()

Comment: Check out my updated answer. And once again, you cannot use intent to launch Fragment directly.